# Añadir datos a csv sin sobreescribir el contenido previo

Tags: python, csv

estoy intentando comprender el manejo de archivos csv mediante `pandas`.

La cosa es que quiero ir creando un archivo al cual cada vez se le irá añadiendo más información.

Lo primero que hago es comprobar si existe o no el fichero `.csv`. Si no existe lo creo y le guardo la información deseada. (Hasta aquí creo que lo hago bien)

Mi problema viene en el segundo caso, en el `else`. ¿Cómo hago para añadir nuevos datos al csv? Por ahora solo consigo sobreescribirlo, y yo lo que quiero es que esté toda la info previa, más la nueva.

Se me ha ocurrido (pero no me termina de salir) leer todo `data.csv`, guardar su contenido en una lista, guardar el nombre las columnas también, y finalmente reescribir todo el fichero de nuevo. Pero imagino tiene que haber algo más eficiente que esto, pues si el archivo es de 3 filas no pasa nada, pero cómo tenga un millón...

```
import os
import pandas as pd


# *********************************************** DATOS POR SI NO EXISTE ARCHIVO
data1 = [['Miguel', 2018, 'Visión art.', 9.5],
        ['Natalia', 2019, 'Data Science', 8],
        ['Severino', 2019, 'Raspberry', 7],
        ['Magnolia', 2015, 'Intel. art.', 9.8]]
columnas = ['Nombre', 'Año', 'Asignatura', 'Nota final']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=columnas)

# *********************************************** DATOS POR SI SI EXISTE. AÑADIR DATOS
data2 = [['Nau', 2017, 'Face Detec', 5],
        ['Uan', 2016, 'Control', 8.2]]
# ***********************************************



if not os.path.isfile('data/data.csv'):
    df1.to_csv(r'data/data.csv', index=None, header=True)

else:
    data = pd.read_csv('data/data.csv')
    print(pd.DataFrame(data))
```

Nota: Los datos que hay allí están para hacer las pruebas para ambos casos mientras entiendo como funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `pandas.to_csv` le puedes pasar mediante el argumento `mode` la forma en que quieres que el archivo sea abierto, los modos son exactamente los mismo que los que permite [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) Simplemente puedes usar el modo `append` (`a`) el cual abre el archivo en modo escritura, escribiendo al final del archivo si existe o creándolo en caso contrario. Solo tienes que condicionar si se debe o no agregar la cabecera en función de si el archivo existe o no previamente:

```
path = "data/data.csv"
df1.to_csv(path, index=None, mode="a", header=not os.path.isfile(path))
```

Un ejemplo reproducible basado en tus ejemplos:

```
import os
import pandas as pd



columnas = ['Nombre', 'Año', 'Asignatura', 'Nota final']

data1 = [['Miguel', 2018, 'Visión art.', 9.5],
         ['Natalia', 2019, 'Data Science', 8],
         ['Severino', 2019, 'Raspberry', 7],
         ['Magnolia', 2015, 'Intel. art.', 9.8]]

data2 = [['Nau', 2017, 'Face Detec', 5],
         ['Uan', 2016, 'Control', 8.2]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=columnas)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=columnas)

path = "data/data.csv"
df1.to_csv(path, index=None, mode="a", header=not os.path.isfile(path))
df2.to_csv(path, index=None, mode="a", header=not os.path.isfile(path))
```

Si cabe la remota posibilidad de que el archivo exista pero esté vacío, deberíamos comprobar también esta eventualidad:

```
not (os.path.isfile(path) and os.stat(path).st_size != 0)
```

Obviamente, esto agrega las filas del DataFrame al final del csv existente (o lo crea si no existe) sin más, no va a tener en cuenta para nada el contenido previo. Si el contenido previo es relevante a la hora de agregar nuevas filas, por ejemplo quieres evitar filas repetidas, entonces debes cargar el csv en un DataFrame, operar en él (añadiendo filas, eliminado duplicados, etc) y luego sobrescribir el fichero.

---

### Edición

El argumento `header` permite especificar si como primera línea del csv se agregan los nombres de las columnas o no (cabecera). Puedes pasar:

- **Una lista de cadenas**: en este caso las cadenas de la lista se usan como nombres para las columnas.
- **`True`**: se usa el nombre de las columnas del DataFrame.
- **`False`**: no se escriben los nombres de las columnas en el csv.
  es decir, el nombre de las columnas.

En nuestro caso le pasamos `True` si el archivo no existe o `False` si el archivo existe (ya tiene su cabecera en teoría). Esto es así porque `os.path.isfile(path)` retorna `True` si la ruta existe y es un archivo y `False` en caso contrario, como queremos pasar `False` si el archivo existe y `True` si no existe, simplemente negamos la salida del método con `not` (`not os.path.isfile(path)`).

Por lo que si el archivo no existe los nombres de las columnas del DataFrame se agregan como primera fila del csv, si ya existe no se agrega nada. Si no hacemos esto, nos encontraríamos con una línea con los nombres de las columnas cada vez que agregamos:

> Nombre,Año,Asignatura,Nota final
>   Miguel,2018,Visión art.,9.5
>   Natalia,2019,Data Science,8.0
>   Severino,2019,Raspberry,7.0
>   Magnolia,2015,Intel. art.,9.8
>   Nombre,Año,Asignatura,Nota final
>   Nau,2017,Face Detec,5.0
>   Uan,2016,Control,8.2

en vez de:

> Nombre,Año,Asignatura,Nota final
>   Miguel,2018,Visión art.,9.5
>   Natalia,2019,Data Science,8.0
>   Severino,2019,Raspberry,7.0
>   Magnolia,2015,Intel. art.,9.8
>   Nau,2017,Face Detec,5.0
>   Uan,2016,Control,8.2

Algunos ejemplos:

- `df1.to_csv(data.csv, index=None, header=True)`

  **data.csv**

  > Nombre,Año,Asignatura,Nota final
  >   Miguel,2018,Visión art.,9.5
  >   Natalia,2019,Data Science,8.0
- `df1.to_csv(data.csv, index=None, header=False)`

  **data.csv**

  > Miguel,2018,Visión art.,9.5
  >   Natalia,2019,Data Science,8.0
- `df1.to_csv(data.csv, index=None, header=["Name", "Year", "Course", "Final mark"])`

  **data.csv**

  > Name,Year,Course,Final mark
  >   Miguel,2018,Visión art.,9.5
  >   Natalia,2019,Data Science,8.0